# AWS what is EC2 CPUCredits and how to tag it to use Cost management and billing?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-billing

I'm trying to organize my billing with tag, i'm using a Tag called Project, no but i got a lot of objects with the tag NoProject.
So right now i got the following information from cost management.
Image -> [AWS billing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHkiS.png)

Those are my EC2 instances in us-east-2, they're tagged but not that **USE2-CPUCredits:t3a**, so how can i tag that option to reduce that NoProject, and have a better result for my billing discovery.

Comment: Those credits are for t3 unlimited instances. it means they are using more CPU than their burst threshold and that's what the charge is for. No ideas on tagging

Comment: @eric-fiegehen - For tagging practice your can refer [Tagging Best Practices](https://d1.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/aws-tagging-best-practices.pdf) document from AWS.